# Coffee and blood pressure

Tags: caffeine, health

Several times one hears that drinking too much coffee produces an increase in blood pressure, that may be dangerous with people with cardiovascular diseases.

Is it caffeine the only chemical to blame for this?

I wonder this because Tea and Mate (and also Chocolate) contain caffeine as well, and I've never heard of such a danger regarding to Tea and Chocolate.

Comment: Actually, the effects are not that clear cut. If you look at studies regarding the effects of caffeine on blood pressure they mostly conclude that the effect is present but very small when ingested through coffee or that it's unclear (effect not significant or present in some and absent in other study participants).

Answer (score 4):

Caffeine is not that only drug that can raise blood pressure.  In fact many other drugs are much better at raising blood pressure and have fewer side effects.  If you are asking specifically about the chemicals in coffee, then yes, caffeine is the likely culprit if coffee causes raised blood pressure in an individual.

Tea and chocolate also contain caffeine, but of course lower concentration than what is found in coffee.  Eating large amounts of chocolate or drink large quantities of tea could have a similar effect to drinking moderate amounts of coffee.